# Coalesce a column to a value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am reading a DF from S3. This is what my schema looks like -

**File 1 -**

```
root

|-- patient: long (nullable = true)
 |-- payment1: double (nullable = true)
```

**File 2 -**

```
root

|-- patient: long (nullable = true)
 |-- payment2: double (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to coalesce the payment fields but unable to do so successfully. I am needing to do this because I need to add the two payment fields and both of them can be NULL or empty.

I have tried the following so far -

1. `df.na.fill` - Doesn't work because I have empty strings
2. `.select(when(col("payment1") === "", 0.0).otherwise(col("payment1"))`

Using the above two methods when I add the two columns I still get a NULL if one value is NULL or empty.

Comment: where do you have "empty strings"? According to your schema, there are no strings at all

Comment: Maybe using `coalesce` function?
`when(coalesce(col("payment1"), col("payment2")).isNull, 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty and null using when method, replace it with lit(0) and caste it to double (if the datatype of column is other than double, otherwise casting is not required).

```
file1Df.withColumn("payment1",
  when(col("payment1") === "" or col("payment1").isNull,lit(0))
    .otherwise(col("payment1")).cast(DoubleType))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.